# Postgresql: Assembling subsets of columns and subquery results into a JSON document

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

(I'm playing around with using Postgresql 9.3 to do some of the lifting require to assemble a JSON data structure.)

Given the following schema:

```
person
  id integer,
  name text,
  age integer

job
  id references person,
  title text
```

is it possible to use Postgresql's JSON functions to return something like

```
| id | personalia                 | jobs                                         |
|----|----------------------------|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | {"name": "kim", "age": 55} | [{"title": "Plumber"}, {"title": "manager"}] |
```

i.e. to select a subset of columns and even do a sub query/join to produce an array based on data from another table that matches some criteria (here: person.id = job.id).

Reading through the Postgresql JSON documentation, I see the building blocks are there, but I don't see how to do more advanced stuff like the above scenario – possibly because I lack the SQL know-how.

Comment: any chance you could use 9.4? it would be an easier answer for me!

Comment: @Greg: Not for quite some time, unfortunately. However, that's really interesting to hear! I'd really like to know how this can be done in 9.4. In 9.3 it's already possible to use Postgresql to assemble quite complex JSON data structures directly.

Answer (score 3):

If using Postgres >= 9.4 this can be done using [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) and [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    json_build_object(
      'name', p.name,
      'age', p.age
    ) AS personalia,
    json_agg(
      json_build_object(
        'title', j.title
      )
    ) AS jobs
  FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN job j USING (id)
  GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    id,
    format('{"name": %s, "age", %s}', to_json(name), to_json(age))::json as personalia,
    array_to_json(array_agg(title)) as jobs
from
    person p
    left join
    (
        select id, format('{"title": %s}', to_json(title))::json as title
        from job
    )
    job j using (id)
group by id, name, age
```